# HTML5 Video Issues

Tags: html5-video

Trying to get good html5 video on my site. here are the issues and observation, observed locally:

IN Firefox
 1. when you pass the mouse over the video, video stutters, audio continues
 2. the first video plays the best but not as well as in chrome 
 3. The 2 other videos don't play well, audio runs but video stutter/stops

In Chrome
 1. Poster image visible on video 1, not visible on videos 2 and 3 - u just see the controls
 2. video plays well, when you pass the mouse over the video, no stutter...pause and play works well
    on all 3 videos...

Perhaps the ogg format is not as smooth as mp4 ? Also, I'm not clear on changes in code required when **running more than 1 video on a page**. I did add an id, but there is no corresponding css so I'm just not clear on that...

Here is the code I am using:

```
<video id="vid2" video controls= "controls" preload="metadata" width="640" height="360" poster="video-blog/clarkekoiblog-greenhouse.jpg" tabindex="0">
<source src="video-blog/clarkekoiblog-greenhouse.mp4" type="video/mp4"><!--for chrome,safari-->
<source src="video-blog/clarkekoiblog-greenhouse.ogv" type="video/ogg"><!--for firefox-->
<source src="video-blog/clarkekoiblog-greenhouse.webmvp8.webm" type="video/webm">
<p><em> If you do not see a video here, please refer to the info at the bottom of the page</em></p>
</video>
```

Looking for comments, a solution whatever to make this work.
THANK YOU

Comment: <video id="vid2" video controls= "controls" preload="metadata" width="640" height="360" poster="video-blog/clarkekoiblog-greenhouse.jpg" tabindex="0">
<source src="video-blog/clarkekoiblog-greenhouse.mp4" type="video/mp4"><!--for chrome,safari-->
<source src="video-blog/clarkekoiblog-greenhouse.ogv" type="video/ogg"><!--for firefox-->
<source src="video-blog/clarkekoiblog-greenhouse.webmvp8.webm" type="video/webm">
<p><em> If you do not see a video here, please refer to the info at the bottom of the page</em></p>
</video>

Comment: did you still have this problem ? I have few experiences in html5 video, that I think can be related with this